# How to change color of searched text in the minibuffer when M-x activated?

Tags: minibuffer, coloring

When I type `M-x` along with some text, the found text's background and font color is hard to read (gray and bold white on top of dark blue). Is it possible to change it?

Example screenshot:

[image]

---

As theme I am using [dracula](https://draculatheme.com/emacs/) along with `ivy`.

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")
(load-theme 'dracula t)

(ivy-mode)
(setq ivy-use-virtual-buffers t)
(setq ivy-initial-inputs-alist nil)
(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)

(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'counsel-M-x)
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-r") 'counsel-minibuffer-history)
```

ivy faces (I believe all are default setup):

### [image]

I was not able to do proper test using `emacs -Q` but it makes the found substring as bold without changing its background.

example:

[image]

Comment: If you are using `ivy` you can customize the `minibuffer` faces using `C-h v` -> `ivy-minibuffer-faces` -> `customize`

Comment: Please specify anything relevant that you are using, besides theme dracula. Or do you see the problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file) and then just enable that theme? Put all relevant info in the question, please.

Comment: I updated my answer not sure its enough. I am not sure its related to theme could be related to my ivy configuration.

Comment: @ 46_and_2 I have checked ivy faces but it does not show any color for me to set

Comment: You can try `M-x [customize group]` -> `ivy-faces`. There are all kinds of faces you can set here including `ivy minibuffer match highlight` etc.

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, please post the solution as an answer, not as an update to the question. You can answer your own questions. This is helpful, because it removes the question from the 'unanswered' list.

Comment: @46_and_2 I made changes in ivy-faces but I does not get saves even I do `Apply and Save`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@46_and_2's comment help me to solve to problem I was facing.

> If you are using ivy you can customize the minibuffer faces using C-h v -> ivy-minibuffer-faces -> customize –
>
> You can try M-x [customize group] -> ivy-faces. There are all kinds of > faces you can set here including ivy minibuffer match highlight etc

---

It was all related to ivy color configuration. Its not perfect but I was able to come up with following coloring from here (https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/2717)

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(require 'swiper)

(progn
  (set-face-attribute 'ivy-current-match nil :foreground "white")
  (set-face-attribute 'ivy-minibuffer-match-face-2 nil :foreground "white" :background "red")
  (set-face-attribute 'ivy-minibuffer-match-face-3 nil :foreground "white" :background "darkgreen")
  (set-face-attribute 'ivy-minibuffer-match-face-4 nil :foreground "white" :background "blue")
  ;;
  (set-face-attribute 'swiper-match-face-2         nil :foreground "white" :background "red")
  (set-face-attribute 'swiper-match-face-3         nil :foreground "white" :background "darkgreen")
  (set-face-attribute 'swiper-match-face-4         nil :foreground "white" :background "blue"))
```

Output:

[image]